# Maven Build Jar

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, repository

I am working on Maven project and I have a jar app-client.jar which have dependency on app-core.jar. So I have a pom.xml for app-client.jar and that pom.xml has dependency of app-core so we added dependency of app-core in this pom.xml.
Now I wanna use the app-client.jar in my main project. Because this jar is build locally and not available at remote repository. So I did add the app-client and also specify the location repository  where it will located.
as following..

> ```
> <repositories>
>    <repository>
>        <id>repo</id>
>        <releases>
>            <enabled>true</enabled>
>            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
>        </releases>
>        <snapshots>
>            <enabled>false</enabled>
>        </snapshots>
>        <url>file://${project.basedir}/../lib</url>
>    </repository>
> <repositories>
> <dependencies>
>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
>        <artifactId>app-client</artifactId>
>        <version>1.0</version>
>    </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

and also I put my jar as following
[My Module] / [com] / [sample] /[app-client] /[1.0]/app-client-1.0.jar

When I run mvn clean install I got error app-client's pom.xml not found. and build get failed. Usually when I use single jar then its working fine, but if I use jar having dependency with other  jar it getting failed.

So how can I build my app-client jar and their pom so that it behave normal and also deploy app-core.jar too.

Comment: Same question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300875/7339164

Answer (score 1):

firstly when you are building app-client.jar build a fat jar which includes app-core.jar dependency.

Next copying app-client-1.0.jar into the specified location of local repo doesn't work, to add this jar into your local repo use this command `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`.

Comment: In my project I have lots of dependencies, so I don't want to add list in the given command. Second if I add app-core.jar dependency in my project's pom then also its working fine. But it should be deploy automatically for app-client.jar.

Comment: to deploy app-core with app-client build a fat jar.

Comment: One should avoid to use fat jars as dependencies. Fat jars are purely for creating stand-alone applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you build `app-client.jar` with `mvn clean install`, then it will be installed into your Maven local repository (`.../.m2/repository`). Then any other project on the same computer can reference it in its pom without further information. So no `<repositories>` entry necessary.

If you want to work with multiple people on the same project, use a Nexus/Artifactory server to share the jars.

Solutions with lib folders and system paths are deprecated and cause trouble.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply and thanks for update. In my case app-client.jar and app-core.jar is provided by someone else, I am not building it on my machine. In that case what should I do? By adding that jar in .m2 folder will solve my problem?

Comment: You can use `mvn install:install-file` to install the jars locally in your Maven local repository. Better would be to check out the projects yourself and build them. Even better would be using a repository manager like Nexus/Artifactory (if the other artifacts come from somebody else on your development team).